# \makecvtitle doesn't work with moderncv in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, titles, moderncv

I have a problem with the following tex excerpt in relation to `moderncv` on MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

I do not get the title of my CV.

```
"! Undefined control sequence.
l.44 \makecvtitle
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."
```

The line `\makecvtitle` is part of my template, that compiles fine on Linux with TeX Live. I use pdflatex, also tried tex. No change. 
Can somebody help me to target this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                        % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{orange}                          % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}    % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\firstname{Mari}
\familyname{Wayne}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks as if your moderncv is outdated. Check for updates (in admin mode *and* as user).